# How can i find out the symbol name the compiler generated for my code?

Tags: objective-c, gcc, compiler-construction, symbols, llvm

I know this is pretty much a stupid question. I know almost nothing about how compiler really works.

But recently I want find what symbol name does the compiler generate for my ivar, my methods.
Where and how can I know the answer? (I have only used some IDEs. So if the solution is better to be simple . And it would be great help if the instructions you provide is really  explicit)

(By the way,is there any reference that i can learn about the things like this?)

PS.I'm IOS developer.And if gcc and LLVM works different answer on this question , I would like to know both.

Comment: it isnt really a stupid question. One thing to consider GCC compiles C, C++, Java, Objective-C, Objective-C++, Pascal and others. All these languages are designed and work differently and have different capabilities so GCC or Llvm don't do just one thing. Sounds like what you really want to know is how C and Objective-c are compiled. As Objective-c is 'on top' of C you probably want to study C first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [nm](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nm.1.html) to dump the content of a binary object. Then, each compiler has its own way of mangling. I suggest you have a look at [Name mangling for objective C in wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_Objective-C), it will help you understand how mangling works.

Answer (score 0):

Surely GCC and Clang must have compatible name-mangling schemes, since they can use each other's code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XCode 3 select a source file and then pick "Show Assembly Code" from the Build menu.

Apparently XCode 4 users do not need assembly code :-(